# add line breaks to paragraph from textarea

Tags: jquery

I have a `textarea` box where the user types in a message then it outputs into a `paragraph` markup.
I am successful capturing the text but cannot seem to capture the line breaks.
[heres my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/9a68r/1/)

Ideally a string substitution such as `<br/>` or `\n` is what i was looking for.
 
any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
var txtBox = $('#myTextArea');
var txt = txtBox.val();

txtBox.keyup(function(){
        txt = txtBox.val();
        $('p.msg').html(txt);
});

txtBox.keydown(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 13) {
                $('p.msg').append('<br />');//ApplyLineBreaks(txt);
        }
});
```

and the markup

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" class="form_0" name="Enter your message" type="text"></textarea>
<p class="msg" style="text-align: center;">msg here</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with just the keydown event:

```
var txtBox = $('#myTextArea');
txtBox.keydown(function(e){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("p.msg").html(that.value.replace(/\n/g,"<br />"));
    },10);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NJwhC/3/

The `setTimeout` is important, it allows the `this.value` to be populated before accessing it.

Comment: `replace(/\n/g,"<br />")` would get all line breaks

Comment: Change `keydown` to `keyup` and you don't need setTimeout anymore

Comment: @DigitalD The purpose of using keydown is it is more instant than keyup, far better user experience in my opinion. keyup doesn't register until you lift the key, where as keydown with a 10 ms delay gives an instant response to the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use CSS to tell the element to preserve whitespace:

```
p.msg {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
}​
```

And simplify your JS code:

```
var $txtBox = $('#myTextArea');

$txtBox.keyup(function(){
    $('p.msg').text($txtBox.val());
}).trigger('keyup')​;
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9a68r/4/**

Comment: thank you, but i will need some kind of markup for the break for this particular issue

Comment: the css solution does not insert `<br/>` values and i will need some kind of markup to indicate line breaks for this particular question.  on the 3rd line i have "Ideally a string substitution such as <br/> or \n is what i was looking for."

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your `<br>`s in the `keyup` function.  Get rid of the `keydown` function and change the `keyup` to:

```
txtBox.keyup(function(){
    $('p.msg').html(txtBox.val().replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `keyup` handler will overwrite the contents of `p.msg` immediately after `keydown` is run. Use this in your keyup:

```
$('p.msg').html(txt.replace("\n","<br/>"));
```

Comment: keydown does see special keys, which special keys were you referring to? see http://jsfiddle.net/NJwhC/3/

Comment: I wasn't paying attention and realized that the keyup was firing right after the keydown so whatever happened in keydown was overwritten.