# How to preserve white spaces and new line in jquery append text

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, append

I am submitting textarea using ajax and when I append the response to a class it shows the dummy only when if there is no new line in text area .

HTML

```
   <p id="updateres_n"></p>
   <div class="update_res"></div>
```

ajax code

```
success: function(response){
     document.getElementById('upd_msg').innerHTML="updated";
     $('.update_res').append(response);
  }
```

php code

First inserts textarea and `print_r` new updated text in javascript

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('updateres_n').innerHTML="<?php print_r (nl2br($updated_text));?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear on what is the problem you are facing

Comment: using ajax i submits the text and through jquery and javascript it shows dummy of  the inserted text but dummy only shows text if there is no new line in text but i want to show new line as well... what's not clear??

Comment: This link can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482507/add-line-breaks-to-paragraph-from-textarea

Comment: No it is not clear. What is `dummy of the inserted text`? Please show input and expected and actual output - use pictures if needed

Comment: preview my friend

Comment: This would not work with whitespace present in the php var `document.getElementById('updateres_n').innerHTML="<?php print_r (nl2br($updated_text));?>"` You could use a backtick in newest browsers: `document.getElementById('updateres_n').innerHTML=\`<?php print_r (nl2br($updated_text));?>\``

Comment: What is `updateres_n` ? You see your question is not really clear at all. Please read [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by css, use this and you're done...

```
.update_res {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

also give this css to the textarea also...